# Install TensorFlow 2.2 on Windows with Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, anaconda, windows-installer

How do I install TensorFlow 2.2 with Nvidia Geforce GTX 1650 with Anoconda (on Windows 10)

I want to know whether this anaconda command will work instead of manually installing all the required files like `CUDA toolkit`, `CUdnn` and `TensorRT` (for TensorFlow version 2.2 GPU).

```
$conda create Test Tensorflow-gpu==2.1

$conda activate Test

$pip3 install Tensorflow-gpu==2.2
```

Note: I will manually download the GPU driver as recommended on tensorflow official website!

I do `pip3 install tensorflow-gpu` (for version 2.2) because as per TensorFlows Official website both 2.1 & 2.2 use the same CUDA & cuDNN version.

Answer (score 0):

Right now it looks like Anaconda's highest version of Tensorflow is 2.1.  If you want 2.2 you'll need to install tensorflow gpu, cuda, and cudnn manually.